# How To Use CSS To Add Multiple Fonts In One Paragraph?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to get a title and text into one paragraph. The title, however, should have another font than the text. I could get it to work using a lot of `<div>`'s but it's hard to do it that way. I'm looking to do it without a lot of `<div>`'s but i figured it might be impossible without any `<div>`'s. Here's my code:

```
<div class="blue">
<p class="font2">
Bits
</p>
<br>
<p class="font1">
Een bit is een kleine schakelaar die open of gesloten is. 
De bit krijgt de waarde 1 of 0 als de schakelaar open of gesloten is.
De enen en nullen kunnen worden gezien als ja en nee of aan en uit.
Computers gebruiken deze waarden om informatie op te slaan en te lezen.
</p>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

I'd also like to ask another question:

```
 #menu1 a {display: block; background-color: #0066FF; text-decoration: none; font-family: calibri; font-size: 20px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px 5px;} 
    #menu1 a:hover {background-color: #0088FF} 
    #menu1 li {display: inline-block;} 
    #menu1 ul {list-style: none; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; padding:0px;}
```

Here's my code. I'm trying to get it all under one `#menu1` Because i'm working with multiple menu's and i don't want to lose my overview.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to use spans? They can be used inside of paragraphs and this way you could "mark" the text you want, to use different font.

Comment: you can't ask another question her and that question has no use, because it hard to make that in under one and its impossible `css` has certain rules

Comment: Ask *one* question at a time. Make sure you are asking the right questions(s). You should apparently first ask “how do I use HTML properly” (you are now using `p` for something that you clearly want to be a heading) and “how do I learn CSS”, but these are too broad for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try this simple method using span

best way to add class to text is using `<span>` and to change style use `font-family:`

```css
.bold {
  font-family: cursive
}

.italic {
  font-family: fantasy
}

.underline {
  font-family: monospace
}

.italic {
  font-family: serif
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
  <p class="font2">
    Bits
  </p>
  <br>
  <p class="font1">
    <span class="bold">Een bit is een kleine schakelaar die open of gesloten is.</span>
    <span class="italic">De bit krijgt de waarde 1 of 0 als de schakelaar open of gesloten is.</span>
    <span class="underline">De enen en nullen kunnen worden gezien als ja en nee of aan en uit.</span>
    <span class="boldit">Computers gebruiken deze waarden om informatie op te slaan en te lezen.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You should try to simplify your HTML markup as show in the answer by @Bobby Jack, you will only get benefit from it, since you wanted to reduce the number of elements

Comment: Yup, even if you really *do* want the slightly unorthodox styling in that paragraph, you can still get rid of the superfluous `br`, style the title in a proper heading tag (`h*n*`), and - probably - remove the enclosing `div`.

Comment: @sodawillow we don't what `.font2` css contain so as O P wants to change style i answered and rest he will make, we can't make project here only error and some simple example(idea)

Comment: *"I could get it to work using a lot of <div>'s but it's hard to do it that way. I'm looking to do it without a lot of <div>'s"* / you added 4 elements :) --- Anyway, you got the reward :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have much better luck with slightly-reworked HTML, to improve the structure. For example:

```
<h2>Bits</h2>

<p>
Een bit is een kleine schakelaar die open of gesloten is. 
De bit krijgt de waarde 1 of 0 als de schakelaar open of gesloten is.
De enen en nullen kunnen worden gezien als ja en nee of aan en uit.
Computers gebruiken deze waarden om informatie op te slaan en te lezen.
</p>
```

The `h2` should be at whatever level is appropriate.

Now, you can style that as you wish by targetting the `h2` and the `p`. If you want them grouped, for semantic reasons, you can wrap both in a `section` element. Otherwise, if you wish to style each separately from other `h2` / `p` elements in your document, you can apply a class to each.

Now, what styles do you wish to apply to each element? As an example, you can start with:

```
h2 { font-family: sans-serif; }
 p { font-family: serif; }
```

Based on another answer, and the title of this question, would it be correct to say you want each sentence in the paragraph to have potentially different styles?

Comment: plus one for semantic markup, font is already different (bigger, bold) with h2 :)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your text in a `span` and add a `class` it's `inline` by default and won't break your lines:

```
<p>some text <span class="font1">with a headline</span> and some other text in the same paragraph with <span class="font2">another headline</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have your styles in an external stylesheet, at this point I'm assuming not, so in you head tag put:

```
<style>
.font1{
   font-family:arial /* put whatever font you want here */
}
.font2{
   font-family:helvetica /* put whatever font you want here */
}
</style>
```

you should externalize your styles if you aren't, and I'd look into using h1, h2, h3 tags etc instead of p elements for titles

Comment: if you have h1, h2, h3 font size will differ

Comment: is that a problem? OP's question was how to make the fonts different, this does that. Its simply a suggestion, and he actually never says the font size needs to stay the same, just wants different fonts